# How do you determine what exception is thrown from an external library without debugging symbols?

Tags: c++, gdb, try-catch

I'm having some problems with a C++ piece of code similar to the one below:

```
try {

        /* some code here */

} catch(...) {

        /* ... */
}
```

I'm stepping through the code contained in the try block with the gdb and at some point something is being thrown. I cannot really know what it is because the function call that throws comes from a library and has no debugging symbols associated with it.

Is there a way for the gdb to determine what is being caught in the catch block ?

Comment: Have you tried printing the exception in the catch statement? Maybe that will lead you to understand more clearly where the exception is coming from (even without using gdb)

Comment: If the library doesn't document its public API (including what it throws) you should *strongly* consider making a different library choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `call current_exception()`, which if supported on your platform will return an `exception_ptr` for the current exception. It's not specified exactly what's contained in an exception_ptr however, but you could inspect it with `x` to see if you can figure something out.

It's also likely that some register contains the current exception data, but you didn't specify what architecture you're using.